# The type initializer for 'Neo4jClient.GraphClient' threw an exception

Tags: c#, nosql, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm new to Neo4j, when I tried to connect to Neo4j server through neo4jclient in the C#, my code have faced to an exception such as image below:
[image: Neo4j exception thrwon]

the Error is :

> The type initializer for 'Neo4jClient.GraphClient' threw an
>   exception.

and the InnerException is:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed

-> also The  `http://localhost:7474/db/data`   is the root.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clearly read in the inner exception that it can't load the assembly `Newtonsoft.Json`. Reference `Newtonsoft.Json`, preferable by using [NuGet](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog).

Comment: If you use nuget to get the Neo4jclient it will automatically get the Newtsonsoft.Json as part of the install...